# Using xargs for parallel Python scripts

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing, xargs

I currently have a bash script, script.sh, with two nested loops. The first enumerates possible values for a, and the second enumerates possible values for b, like

```
#!/bin/sh
for a in {1..10}
do
    for b in {1..10}
    do
        nohup python script.py $a $b &
    done
done
```

So this spawns off 100 Python processes running script.py, one for each (a,b) pair. However, my machine only has 5 cores, so I want to cap the number of processes at 5 to avoid thrashing/wasteful switching. The goal is that I am always running 5 processes until all 100 processes are done.

xargs seems to be one way to do this, but I don't know how to pass these arguments to xargs. I've checked other similar questions but don't understand the surrounding bash jargon well enough to know what's happening. For example, I tried

```
seq 1 | xargs -i --max-procs=5 bash script.sh
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything - script.sh runs as before and still spawns off 100 processes.

I assume I'm misunderstanding how xargs works.

Thanks!

Comment: `xargs` can't, and doesn't, change how its subprocesses *start their own children*; rather, it provides control over how it starts its subprocesses.

Comment: In the case of Python I'd actually suggest to use the Python `multiprocessing` module instead of `xargs`. Or alternatively the GNU `parallels` utility. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @Wolph, I definitely agree re: multiprocessing. As for GNU parallel -- it's a larger, more complicated and hairier codebase than `xargs`, which is a model of simplicity in comparison. Given a Pythonist's preference for simplicity, I'd consider xargs the obvious choice among the two. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's fair. But at the same time it enables much more control over how the parallel processes are being executed and it's more portable than GNU specific xargs extenstions :)

Comment: @Wolph, not GNU-specific; `--max-procs` is a GNUism, but `-P` works on OS X and modern FreeBSD as well.

Comment: Brace expansion is a `bash` feature; if you are going to use any shebang, use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would actually look more like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in {1..10}; do
  for b in {1..10}; do
    printf '%s\0' "$a" "$b"
  done
done | xargs -0 -x -n 2 -P 5 python script.py
```

Note that there's no `nohup`, nor any `&` -- to track the number of concurrent invocations, `xargs` needs to be directly executing the Python script, and that process can't exit until it's complete.

The non-standard (but widely available) `-0` extension requires input to be in NUL-delimited form (as created with `printf '%s\0'`); this ensures correct behavior with arguments having spaces, quotes, backslashes, etc.

The likewise non-standard `-P 5` sets the maximum number of processes (in a way slightly more portable than `--max-procs=5`, which is supported on GNU but not modern BSD xargs).

The `-n 2` indicates that each instance of the Python script receives only two arguments, thus starting one per pair of inputs.

The `-x` (used in conjunction with `-n 2`) indicates that if a single Python instance can't be given two arguments (for instance, if the arguments are so long that both can't fit on a single command line), this should be treated as a failure, rather than invoking a Python instance with only one argument.

Comment: Fails in Cygwin with: -bash: fi: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `for'
-bash: fi: line 4: `  for b in {1..10}'

Comment: @OleTange, I was missing some `; do`s -- that's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you use bash, then the following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for a in {1..10}
do
    for b in {1..10}
    do
        if [ `jobs | wc -l` -lt 6 ]; then # less than 6 background jobs
            nohup python script.py $a $b &
        else
            wait -n   # wait for any background job to terminate
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Take out the `nohup` if you want `wait` or `jobs` to work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It works with `nohup` as well. Tested with `nohup sleep 5&` + `wait`.

Comment: Granted -- it's the shell-builtin cousin `disown` that would have that effect.

Comment: ...isn't `wait -n` a fairly recent addition to the shell, by the way? I want to say it's somewhere post-4.0.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel is made for exactly these kinds of jobs:

```
parallel python script.py ::: {1..10} ::: {1..10}
```

If you need $a and $b placed differently you can use {1} and {2} to refer to the two input sources:

```
parallel python script.py --option-a {1} --option-b {2} ::: {1..10} ::: {1..10}
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel