# Reading lines of file into xargs for parallel python script

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing

I am trying to execute a python script in parallel by using the lines of a file as arguments to a python script. The file is named `experiments.txt` and might look like this:

```
--x_timesteps 3 --y_timesteps 3 --exp_path ./logs
--x_timesteps 4 --y_timesteps 3 --exp_path ./logs
--x_timesteps 5 --y_timesteps 3 --exp_path ./logs
--x_timesteps 6 --y_timesteps 3 --exp_path ./logs
```

I want to speed up the processing by using xargs; however, I don't know how to do this with file input. **How can I parallelize a python script by reading line by line from the file and piping to xargs?**

I know I can solve this problem with a simple for-loop; however, I need to know how to do it with file input.

Typing this into the command line in the appropriate directory,

```
for x in {3..6}; \
do printf '%s\0' "--x_timesteps=${x}" "--y_timesteps=3" "--exp_path=./logs"; \
done | xargs -0 -n 3 -P 8 python script.py
```

The for-loop style parallelization is derived from the answer to ["Using xargs for parallel Python scripts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713719/using-xargs-for-parallel-python-scripts)

Comment: Have you tried something like `< experiments.txt xargs -n 2 -P 8 python script.py` to input the file into xargs?

Comment: I have tried `while read line; do printf '%s\0' "$line"; done < experiments.txt | xargs -0 -n 3 -P 8 python script.py scale_rank3` unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it is simpler and more controllable with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel --dry-run --colsep ' ' python script.py :::: experiments.txt
```

You can simply add or remove `--dry-run` to debug. You can add `--eta` or `--bar` for progress reports. You can distribute tasks across multiple hosts. You can easily do fail/retry processing. You can extract basenames, filenames, directory names from parameters. You can do permutations of parameters. And so on.

Comment: I use Windows 10, but it looks like I can get GNU Parallel through [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/parallel). I will try this and report back shortly.

Comment: There's an excellent PDF by Ole Tange here https://zenodo.org/record/1146014/files/GNU_Parallel_2018.pdf?download=1

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much! I initially tried xargs because that's what my professor uses in the specs for our open lab assignments, but I was struggling to adapt the use of xargs to my personal projects. Thanks again!

Comment: @JaredFrazier GNU Parallel is also supported on CygWin.